# WP Rest API, when using _embed JSON errors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

When I fetch data from this endpoint `http://blog.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1` I get a JSON object.

When I add the _embed param,`http://blog.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&_embed`, I get an image, no JSON.

According to the Wordpress documentation, when you pass the `_embed` parameter, you are supposed to get extra usefull data included in the response - [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_embed)

I just get an actual JPG image returned.

Has anyone seen this before or know what the problem could be? I have to resort to adding custom endpoint to just get extra data back.

Comment: Hi @wind_kind Your question is not much clear, Can you let me know what exactly you would like to sort out?

Comment: @JenilKanani - I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so it turns out that a plugin I'm using to create fake posts (FakePress) for testing was causing the issue. Don't know how but disabling fixes the problem.